# GridView does not load when running Calabash test

Tags: android, cucumber, android-gridview, calabash, calabash-android

I am attempting to run tests on my Android app using Calabash. The main screen of my app has some buttons and a grid view. Each cell of the grid view contains an ImageView. If I start the app via the Calabash console, everything looks great. All images are loaded into the grid, and I can manually execute my test steps.

However, when I attempt to run a test containing these same steps, my grid view is not population upon startup, and therefore I can't use "touch" commands on the images.

Why would I be getting different behavior from running a test?

EDIT: Here are the commands I'm using.

**To run the test:**

(SDK PATH) calabash-android run (APK PATH) features/PTA-3.feature

**To start the console:**

(SDK PATH) calabash-android console (APK PATH)

start_test_server_in_background

Comment: Could you paste the commands you use to start console and to start executing tests?

Comment: @JamesHarpe You should also post the server/client version. Run `client_version` and `server_version` in your console.